# Cakephp 2.x HTML helper for external link not working

Tags: html, hyperlink, helper, cakephp-2.0

I'm doing the following:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('click here', 'www.notw.com', array('target' => '_blank')); ?>
```

Still, the  created points to: mysite.local/current_controller/www.notw.com

How can I make my link to work properly for externals?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you should try `http://www.notw.com` instead of just `www`.

To resolve this w/o the protocol ie. http or https just add `//`
before url and it will auto resolve the protocol for you.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('click here', '//www.notw.com', array('target' => '_blank')); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $this->Html->link('Link Text Here', 'http://www.anywebsiteyouwant.com');
```